# Given an index of choices for each column, construct a 1D array from a 2D array

Tags: arrays, julia

I have a 2D array such as:

```
julia> m = [1 2 3 4 5
            6 7 8 9 10
            11 12 13 14 15]
3×5 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   2   3   4   5
  6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15
```

I want to pick one value from each column and construct a 1D array.

So for instance, if my choices are

```
julia> choices = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 2
 1
```

Then the desired output is `[1, 7, 13, 9, 5]`. What's the best way to do that? In my particular application, I am randomly generating these values, e.g.

```
choices = rand(1:size(m)[1], size(m)[2])
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the simplest approach:

`[m[c, i] for (i, c) in enumerate(choices)]`

EDIT:
If best means fastest for you such a function should be approximately 2x faster than the comprehension for large `m`:

```
function selector(m, choices)
    v = similar(m, size(m, 2))
    for i in eachindex(choices)
        @inbounds v[i] = m[choices[i], i]
    end
    v
end
```